# C# - unsafe swap of a dictionary value by pointers

Tags: c#, performance, pointers, dictionary, unsafe

I have two sets of dictionaries that each contain the same keys and have initialized values.

Using unsafe code, I would like to swap their addresses:

```
Dictionary<string, List<object>> d1 = ...
Dictionary<string, List<object>> d2 = ...
unsafe void SwapEntries(string index)
{
    int* tmp = &d1[index];
    &d1[index] = &d2[index]
    &d2[index] = tmp;
}
```

Assuming I've recalled my pointer arithmetic properly, the output I'm looking for would be this:

```
d1 = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>() { "a", { 1, 2, 3 } };
d2 = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>() { "a", { 4, 5, 6 } };
SwapEntries("a");
Console.WriteLine(d1["a"]); //4,5,6
Console.WriteLine(d2["a"]); //1,2,3
```

However, when I try to write this, I get the compile error "Cannot take the address of the given expression."

1) Is there a faster way of performing the address swap that I've missed? Performance is the only priority here.

2) Is my pointer arithmetic correct?

3) Do I need to move to a wrapper or a different data structure entirely in order to be able to perform the address swap as described?

Comment: Why do you even need to do pointer work, why not just do `SwapEntries(string index) { object tmp = d1[index]; d1[index] = d2[index]; d2[index] = tmp; }` C# classes are reference based (kind of like smart pointers), there is no need to use pointers here.

Comment: Your suggested code makes no sense at all.  You are using `int*`, but `int` is nowhere to be seen in that code snippet.  You have (what would be in other languages) rvalues on the left hand side of an assignment.  And the thing you appear to want to swap, based on the outcome, already *IS* a reference type, so you don't have to form a pointer to it to get handle semantics.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Martin Ullrich's answer.

The expression `d1[index]` is not a variable. It is an invocation of the `get` accessor of the indexer defined by `Dictionary<,>`. You cannot take a pointer to that with the `&` operator.

Besides, in this case, the type of it is `List<object>`. You can only take pointers to value types, and `List<>` is a `class` type.

Even if you did have the true storage location, and it was of type `object[]`, it would still be impossible since the element type of the array is `object`. So `arr[0]` (corresponding to `d1[index][0]`) would be a `class` type again, and you cannot take the address of that.

Scott Chamberlain's comment to your question gives an easy approach. Just use

```
void SwapEntries(string index) 
{
    var tmp = d1[index];
    d1[index] = d2[index];
    d2[index] = tmp; 
}
```

This just involves passing around *references* to the two existing `List<object>` instances in question.

Comment: Figured you would not mind me messing with the formatting of the quoted code :)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain No, that's fine, of course. I did fix a typo in your code, since `object` should have been `List<object>` (otherwise how can we assign `tmp` back with the indexer `set` accessor?). Fixed it with `var`, just to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 1):

Automatic pointers to dictionary members aren't supported - they only work for Arrays or data types that use C# 7's "ref return" feature for indexers, properties or methods.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to actually take the `ref` addresses of the two locations, [there is now an option for it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.collectionsmarshal.getvaluerefornullref?view=net-6.0#system-runtime-interopservices-collectionsmarshal-getvaluerefornullref-2(system-collections-generic-dictionary((-0-1))-0))

```
CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrNullRef(d1, "a")
```

So if you had a `Swap` function which accepted pointers:

```
void Swap<T>(ref T a, ref T b) 
{
    var tmp = a;
    a = b;
    b = tmp;
}
```

You could call it like this

```
Swap(ref CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrNullRef(d1, "x"),
     ref CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrNullRef(d2, "x"));
```

[shaplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQyAMABMugCwDcO+R6AdAEoCuAdsGALYCmNAkixwE4B7AA4BlAQDcwAYw4BnCrgDMRVAQDCBAN44CeoiuQkCogO4BDYQB4AKgD4AFPw4AzAjYLmoBZ248AjAEptXX0wiXN+AmA2YQIAXk9FMLDzBIJ/ZJS9f0TzLL0AX1C9ZENjAFkHABEZVkEmSIBPK2I8bzAWO09vWul6xv4Wto6ujMCdbGy9M0snVw1BCAgOfrAGuQrIuQALcwgaAHEOYAA1fYYOOlcAeX4AOQZl65cHLwIAIgAPD8CoEum+l8i2WqwGm22ewOxzOFyutweTwgLwc/m831+gQKBGK2EKQA==)

The benefit of this over just using normal dictionary indexers is that you only look up each location once, rather than once for get and once for set.

Comment: The `Swap` can be implemented more succinctly like this: `void Swap<T>(ref T a, ref T b) => (a, b) = (b, a);`

Comment: I know, but that results in an extra local variable, which for performance I thought to avoid https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQyAMABMugCwDcO+R6AdAEoCuAdsGALYCmNAkixwE4B7AA4BlAQDcwAYw4BnCrgDMRVAQDCBAN44CeoiuQkCogO4BDYQB4AKgD4AFPw4AzAjYLmoBZ248AjAEptXX0why8ggF4HfyhzQMUwgF9QvWRDYwBZBwARGVZBJnN+AE8rYjxvMBY7T2986ULisor0KoIa4DqgnWwwsLNLJ1cNQQgIDiawIrkskrkAC3MIGgBxDmAANRWGDjpXAHl+ADkGCYOXCO8AIgAPG8CoNIGB3zGJqea5heXVje2u32R1O5wgl1itwegUSL1S2GSQA===

Comment: I hope that they'll optimize this pattern, so that it results in a single temp variable, because it is handy and gives style points. :-)

Comment: It is likely that a good JIT optimizer would optimize the extra variable away, but not worth the risk if you are going for absolute performance